# QWebEngineView: anormal behavior on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, python-3.x, fonts, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm subclassing the QWebEngineView class:

```
class WebViewPerso(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView):


    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(WebViewPerso, self).__init__(parent)
        print(self.settings().fontFamily(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.StandardFont))

        # Get the default font and use it in the view
        self.settings().setFontFamily(
            QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.StandardFont,
            self.font().family())
        print(self.settings().fontFamily(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.StandardFont))
```

On linux, the two print statements return:

```
DejaVu Serif
Sans Serif
```

It clearly indicates I changed the font for the view, and the view now uses the correct font.

With the exact same lines on OSX, I get:

```
Times
.SF NS Text
```

Which also indicates the font was changed. However, the view **still uses the Times font**.

I also tried the setting line on:

```
FixedFont
SerifFont
SansSerifFont
CursiveFont
FantasyFont
PictographFont
```

But my WebEngineView still uses the Times font.

Do you have any idea about why I observe this behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try some methods inherited by it, not just from QWebEngineView.**

1. Something from [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview-members.html). For example setFont passing a [QFont](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontinfo.html)
2. Also try to change it by the font family from its [styleSheet](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html).

***For example, in my code I've just made this:***

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView


class WebView(QWebEngineView):


    def __init__(self):
        super(WebView, self).__init__()
        self.init_ui()


    def init_ui(self):
        self.load(QUrl("http://www.google.com/"))
        self.setFont(QFont("Arial Black"))
```

***and it worked fine in Linux, Windows, OSX, even in Raspberry.***

Comment: I'm sorry but setFont doesn't work on Linux (at least for me). I don't know why though. Is it because I use setHtml to set the content of the view ?

Comment: Could be, even though I use self...load(...) I also use setHtml, so don't know why you are having this problem, sorry "/

Comment: Ok, I have more information. On linux, setFont doesn't work, but I can still use the trick I showed in my question. On Mac OS, the problem comes from the font ```.NS SF Text```. I can use my trick on any other font, but this one. Some permission issue I guess: https://eclecticlight.co/2015/11/10/qa-how-to-use-san-francisco-font-in-docs/. This font is supposed to only be used by the system. Strangely, I can use it anywhere in my software, except in QWebEngineView.

Comment: This f* QWebEngineView is kinda troublesome, since it doesn't use WebKit anymore and Chromium instead I've just hade problem since then. Things like "no sandbox being used", "data requests permission problems", all problems I can imagine "(. Good luck with your problem man, let's rock it up!!

Comment: I opened a bug on Qt's bugtracker. Actually it's not .SF NS Text's fault, it seems some fonts are not "activated". See: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57327